# Can't see material nodes for Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Using Cycles, "Add Nodes" checked, "Object Data" selected, already pressed numpad "0" and also "Home". See screencap below.

How do I get the material visible on the material tab to show its nodes in the node window? Also, the material dropdown under nodes is greyed.

I'm using "Gold Material for Cycles" from Blendswap, so I'm trying to figure out someone else's file.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The nodes might be off screen. Pan around a bit with moddle mouse button or zoom out a lot, you might find them

Comment: I did, also pressed numpad 0 and home.

Comment: I've downloaded the file myself. The material is locked because of the button to the right of "Use Nodes". It currently looks like 2 overlapping circles. Try unchecking that. For me the materials do show up in the node tree, strangely enough

Comment: That solved it, IAmGettingTiredOfAliases. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help!

Comment: @IAmGettingTiredOfAliases you should add that as an answer below.

Comment: Matt, this was my first post here. IAmGettingTiredOfAliases provided the answer. Do I press "Answer the Question" below or is there something someone else does to show this was solved? "Answer the Question" seems to appear as if I'm suggesting that I came up with the answer, so I didn't follow through with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the material is locked in the node editor. Click the two overlapping circles to unlock the material!